# Ajax : cannot get $_SESSION : works in local but not in my web Server

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I am developing a website. 
I use jQuery for updating and deleting from a database. To get the "iduser" I use a session and store the id inside.

In localhost (wamp server) it works fine but when I upload my files on my server (Ubuntu, apache2) it doesn't work.

I have already all checked:

- session_start() are in the two files
- session ids are the same (index.php and ajax.php)
- $_SESSION are set in index.php not in ajax.php
- I have an ajax answer that says that the session is not defined (echo that I wrote).

Maybe there is a rule to as in config file?

index.php

```
<?php
include_once("classRecord.php");
///temporaire
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
    $idUser = $_GET["id"];
else
    $idUser = 1;
session_start();
$_SESSION["idUser"] = $idUser;
[..]
```

script

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php?type=del",
        datatype: 'json',
        data: "idRecord=" + data.idRecord,
        success: function(json){
             console.log(json);   
            }
        }//success
    });//ajax
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json");
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["idUser"];
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Résultats de recherche

I found my problem. on my server the sessions save path was not defined. The default path is not accessible due to restricted access rights. so I modified the line

```
sessions_save_path
```

of the php.ini
Hope this will help someone
Thomas

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer to your question. It's nice to see people leaving this kind of info to help others.